# Regex ignore part of the string in matches

Tags: regex

Suppose I have a tags object as such:

```
["warn-error-fatal-failure-exception-ok","parsefailure","anothertag","syslog-warn-error-fatal-failure-exception-ok"]
```

I would like to be able to use regex to match on "failure" but exclude "warn-error-fatal-failure-exception-ok".

So in the above case if I used my regex to search for failure it should only match failure on parsefailure and ignore the rest.

How can this be accomplished using regex?

**NOTE**: The regex has to exclude the whole string "warn-error-fatal-failure-exception-ok"

Comment: So "failure" can occur within a non-hyphenated word; are there any other constraints besides they hyphen?

Comment: Well not just the hyphen but as a whole exclude the string "warn-error-fatal-failure-exception-ok"

Comment: Try `(?-)failure(?-)`

Comment: @hmedia1 that matches every case of failure, it needs to exclude when it is part of the tag "warn-error-fatal-failure-exception-ok"

Comment: What is a "tags" object? Is that specific to a language?

Comment: It's part of a processing pipeline where an event can get lots of tags associated with it.  What I'm looking for is a way to exclude certain specific tags from the regex search.

Comment: [^warn-error-fatal-]failure - ^ first character of the brackets basically says "not this"

Comment: This -- and situations like it -- are why I wish the formalization of regular expressions included intersection and negation (which, unlike many other "regex" features, doesn't even leave the realm of regularity). In a fictional regex language that supported these, you could just write `(.*failure.*)/\~(warn-error-fatal-failure-exception-ok)`, where ```/\``` is my proposed fictional syntax for intersection and `~` is my proposed fictional syntax for negation. Wouldn't that be grand?

Comment: @ErinHalbmaier In most regex syntaxes, `[^abcde]` matches a *single* character, so long as that character is not a, b, c, d, or e. So I don't think that regex says what you wish it did.

Comment: @Daniel Wagner: Ah, true, brackets. I was thinking about it wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**

*After documenting the answer below, I realized that maybe what you are looking for is:*

```
(?<!warn-error-fatal-)failure(?!-exception-ok)
```

*So I'm adding it here in case that it fits what you are looking for better. This regex is just looking for "failure" but using a [Negative Lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) and a [Negative Lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to specify that "failure" may not be preceded by "warn-error-fatal-" or followed by "-exception-ok".*

**ANSWER DEVELOPED FROM COMMENTS:**

The following regex captures the "failure" substring in the "parsefailure" tag, and it puts it in Group 1:

```
^.*"(?![^"]*warn-error-fatal-failure-exception-ok[^"]*)[^"]*(failure)[^"]*".*$
```

DETAIL

I will break the regex in parts, and I'll explain each. First, let's forget about everything in between the first set of parentheses, and let's just look at the rest.

```
^.*"[^"]*(failure)[^"]*".*$
```

The important part of the regex is what we are trying to capture in the group, which is the word "failure" which itself is a part of a tag surrounded by double-quotes. The regular expression above matches the whole test string, but it focuses on a tag surrounded by double-quotes and containing the substring "failure".

`^.*"` matches any character from the beginning of the string to a quote

`"[^"]*(failure)[^"]*"` matches a tag surrounded by double-quotes and containing the substring "failure". Literally: a double-quote, followed by zero or more characters that are not double-quotes, followed by "failure", followed by zero or more characters that are not double-quotes, followed by a double-quote. The parentheses capture the word "failure" in group 1.

`".*$` matches any character from the double-quote to the end of the test string

Because `[^"]*(failure)[^"]*` matches all tags containing the substring "failure", `^.*"[^"]*(failure)[^"]*".*$` will capture the substring "failure" from the first tag containing the string. In other words, it will capture "failure" from the `warn-error-fatal-failure-exception-ok` tag which is not what we want, so we most exclude the `warn-error-fatal-failure-exception-ok` tag from being a possible match to the tag portion of the regex: `[^"]*(failure)[^"]*`. This is achieved with a [Negative Lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?![^"]*warn-error-fatal-failure-exception-ok[^"]*)
```

This [Negative Lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) basically means: "The regular expression following the [Negative Lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) can't match `[^"]*warn-error-fatal-failure-exception-ok[^"]*`". The `(?!` and `)` are just part of the syntax. You can read more about it [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

MORE BREAKDOWN

`^` matches the beginning of the test string

`.*` matches any character zero or more times

`"` matches a double-quote character

`[^"]*` matches any character other than the double-quote character zero or more times

`(failure)` matches the word "failure", and since it is in parentheses, it will capture it in a group; in this case, it will be captured in group 1 because there is only one set of capturing parentheses. The parentheses of the Negative Lookahead are non-capturing.

`$` matches the end of the test string

Comment: Omits "parsefailure"

Comment: @luis this doesn't work right, it matches only on "arn-error-fatal-failure-exception-ok"]"

Comment: How are you testing it? I used a C++ program, and it worked fine. Whatever you are using must support Negative Lookahead. I'll add the C++ program, and the output to the answer.

Comment: @luis hmm, I tried with perl, ruby, can you try here https://regex101.com/ you can reproduce what I'm seeing.

Comment: @Exocomp Just add `^` to the beginning and `$` to the end to ensure that it tries to match the whole string. (My opinion is that this behavior should be the default in all regex libraries, but not everybody agrees with me, it seems.)

Comment: @DanielWagner When I add ^ to the beginning and $ to the end it doesn't match at all

Comment: @Daniel is correct. When I add `^` and `$` to the regex, it works. I suppose the C++ regex library doesn't require it. I'll fix the regex in the answer, and I won't post the C++ program.

Comment: @Exocomp Works for me. `foo-failure-bar` reports a match no problem, and `warn-error-fatal-failure-exception-ok` does not match.

Comment: Yes, it does. I just tested it at regex101.com. Make sure you don't have an empty line after the string/tag, just the tag on the first line of the test string box.

Comment: I can't get it to work, even on regex101.com, what am I missing?

Comment: @Exocomp, I added the `^` and the `$` to the regex in the answer, so you can copy and paste it from there.

Comment: Let me describe what I am doing. First, start from scratch. Open [link](https://regex101.com) on a new browser window. Then, copy and paste the regex `^(?!.*warn-error-fatal-failure-exception-ok.*).*failure.*$` into the Regular Expression window. Finally, copy and paste: `parsefailure` into the Test String window. It should give you a "Full match".

Comment: @LuisGuzman apologies for the confusion, the test string is actually ["warn-error-fatal-failure-exception-ok","parsefailure","anothertag","syslog-warn-error-fatal-failure-exception-ok"]

Comment: I see what you are doing. You are using the string with all of the tags, and it doesn't match because it has the "warn-error-fatal-failure-exception-ok" substring in it. The regex is design to look at each tag at a time to figure out if it (one single tag) is a match or not.

Comment: So is this what you want? Or what do you expect to happen when you use the "test" string?

Comment: @LuisGuzman that is right the test string is the one with all the tags, not one at a time, so basically it should just match "failure" that is in the "parsefailure" tag and ignore the other tags - at least that is what I was trying to do

Comment: When you say match it, you mean extract that substring?

Comment: Try this: `^.*"(?![^"]*warn-error-fatal-failure-exception-ok[^"]*)([^"]*failure[^"]*)".*$`. It will match the whole string, and it will only match `parsefailure` in "Group 1." I think this may be what you want. Is it?

Comment: @LuisGuzman just mean match on the "failure" in the "parsefailure" case, no extracting or anything

Comment: This, `^.*"(?![^"]*warn-error-fatal-failure-exception-ok[^"]*)[^"]*(failure)[^"]*".*$`, will match on the "failure" in the "parsefailure" case, and it will put it in Group 1. I'm I getting hot? lol

Comment: @LuisGuzman that's going one step further to return the match in a group, however that is essentially it.  You've done it.   At the moment looking at it makes my head hurt.  Maybe you can explain it a bit more in your answer for clarity and I'll accept it. :)

Comment: Sure, I'll edit my answer with it, and I'll add an explanation. :)

Comment: @Exocomp  The  [`(?<!warn-error-fatal-)failure(?!-exception-ok)`](https://regex101.com/r/E4GOh1/1) will fail both `warn-error-fatal-failure` and `failure-exception-ok`. I think you need [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/E4GOh1/2).

Answer (score 0):

[RegularExpression](https://regex101.com/r/kxuhQI/3) : `[A-Za-z-]*(?<!("warn-error-fatal-))failure`

Recognizes parsefailure and "syslog-warn-error-fatal-failure-exception-ok" not the other failure.

Comment: This relies on the - to exclude which is something that will not work for my case, it has to be the string "warn-error-fatal-failure-exception-ok" to exclude.

Comment: [A-Za-z-]*(?<!("warn-error-fatal-))failure

For some reason, Stack overflow omitted my regular expression.